# Running C# code on ARM platform (Sailfish OS)

Tags: c#, c++, qt, arm, interop

I am writting basic C++ project in Sailfish IDE (based on Qt Creator). I am wondering if it's possible to use my very large C# library (pure C#, just exotic mathematic equation solvers) inside C++ project? Development environment is Linux.

Comment: are you using some fancy Framework-Methods in your C# lib? if not you can proably compile it with mono.

Comment: There is a subset of the .NET framework that runs on microprocessors called, oddly enough, .NET Micro Framework. Its meant to be the sole thing running on the MCU though, I'm not sure how you would call into it.

Comment: @SebastianL: no, just additions, multiplications and **for** instructions.

Comment: Thanks @RonBeyer, I will try that!

Comment: BTW, there is interop in the .NET MF that allows you to call *out*, so you could write your "main" program in C# for .NET MF and call into your C++ library.

Comment: Unless Xamarin provides a version for this OS or Microsoft does that, you are probably all by yourself.

Comment: You can compile mono for any arm. The core is written in plain c. So if you give mono a try you can use your lib on any arm based Linux system.